# ROS2 Intermittent node loss on networked client

Tags: ros2, ros-humble

Configuration:

ROS2 Humble on 2 x Ubuntu 22.04 systems.

2 systems linked via WiFi. No network issues - both machines can talk to each other without issue.

ROS2 Publisher IP:  192.168.10.10/16

ROS2 Subscriber IP: 192.168.20.20/16

Both systems have ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=0 and I am not using ROS_DOMAIN_ID.

Not that is should matter, but the publishing is written in C++ and the subscriptions are written in Python.

Publisher system can see ALL nodes and topics published. No issue.

Subscriber system can see most of the Publishers nodes and topics most of the time, but on many occasions, the subscriber cannot list a particular node, but can still list that node's topics!

IE, On the subscriber system:
ros2 node list - no listing for a few particular nodes. Other are fine.
ros2 topic list - can see all of the topics published by the very node that it can't list.
ros2 topic echo /some/topic/name just hangs, presumably waiting for a publication (or confused because the node has gone AWOL.

Interestingly, if I don't source the "workspace"/install/setup.bash, performing a
"ros2 topic echo /some/topic/name" informs me that the message type is invalid which I assume to mean that it has detected the topic's interface but is unfamiliar with. IE, it has read something from the topic? (not sure how ROS2 detects the interface type).

If I restart the ROS2 publishing services that have these missing nodes, all is good again.

Lastly, it also appears, though not fully tested, that the booting order of the 2 systems may play a part in this. If the subscriber system is booted and running before the publisher system, there is a greater chance that the subscriber system will 'see' all nodes and published topics from the publisher system.

I will be extremely grateful for any suggestions and remedies on how to rectify this. I have 2 ugly workarounds that I will test tomorrow, but I would really like to get to the bottom of this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The relationship to startup order suggests that it's a challenge with discovery potentially. And in particular not all wifi connections are the same with different settings such as MTUs and multicast enabled settings. You'll probably want to share a little bit more about your network setup to get help. Another potential option is to try out using RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=cyclonedds making sure that you have installed ros-humble-rmw-cyclonedds-cpp first. Also please edit your results to show [these debugging steps](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/How-To-Guides/Installation-Troubleshooting.html)

Comment: Thanks @Tully I'll give your suggestion a try. Re multicasting, all good but happy to show results if you think it may help.